# Client-side streaming of multiple large arguments in Go

Tags: go, microservices, grpc, rpc

I'm toying with a proof of concept of a gRPC service, where client may call a remote call procedure with multiple large arguments and receive a large object in response. One possible design I can imagine is as follows:

1. Client calls a stub, sending metadata in `Context` which contains information on how the server should process data, how many streams (arguments) are available to it, and what they represent. For the sake of simplicity, let's assume that each stream has the same fixed type and each stream can be split into chunks of fixed size.
2. Based on the metadata, the server chooses what should be done with the data (apply a compression algorithm, codec etc.). In particular, it can ignore a subset of it altogether.
3. Server streams messages to the client; each message is either a chunk of data (partial response) or a request for the next chunk of i-th argument (which client keeps track of), to which the client responds with either the requested chunk or an information that the argument is already exhausted.
4. The server closes the stream when it has sent all chunks of the response.

The description above doesn't include error handling, but this is the general idea.

A very simplified proto definition could therefore look as follows:

```
// sent by client - partial rpc argument
message PartialArg {
  bytes data = 1;
  int32 arg_num = 2;
}

message DataChunk {
  bytes data = 1;
}

message PartialResponse {
  oneof PartialResponseData {
    int32 arg_num = 1;   // server requests that client provide next chunk of arg [arg_num]
    DataChunk data = 2;  // server sends a subsequent chunk of the response
  }
}

service StreamingService {
  rpc ProcessData (stream PartialArg) returns (stream PartialResponse);
}
```

I'm not entirely convinced that this is the optimal approach. Bidirectional communication between client and server in that form feels clunky and inefficient (especially if exchange in point 3. is synchronous, might be better if a server can request multiple chunks at once). I would like the server to be able to read arguments send by the client in any order, for instance first read X chunks of 3rd argument, then Y chunks of 1st argument, then continue reading 3rd argument and ignore the 2nd one altogether. On the client side, input data is procured in a streaming fashion, by reading it in chunks from the disk (possibly with multiple files open at the same time), so a stateful RPC with bidirectional streaming sounds like the most natural approach. What I'm presenting almost feels like a known problem and I wonder if there are any design patterns, frameworks or idioms that would be of help here. Some design choices would be simpler if I opted for multiple unary RPCs instead of one bidirectional one, but maintaining state on client side increases complexity to the point where I really doubt that it's worth it.